# how to format date coming from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

Simple question but i need it :)

```
  $query = "SELECT * 
FROM  `set` 
WHERE ID = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$frmdate = $info['date'];
```

So far i tried

```
$timestamp = strtotime($info['date']);
$joined_date = date("j M. Y", $timestamp);
```

but no luck !

"date" field in mysql is DATE data type

I want to make it like "23 Oct. 2009"

how can i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert the string representation of the date into a timestamp then you can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert the timestamp into whatever format you like:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($frmdate);
$formatted_date = date("j M. Y", $timestamp);
```

You can also move the translation from the yyyy-mm-dd format to timestamp into the query itself, using:

```
select unix_timestamp(field_name) as field_name_timestamp
```

Comment: thx, $frmdate was "2009-10-01" but it resulted "31 Dec. 1969" with your code

Comment: That means, per the documentation of `strtotime`, that `$frmdate` wasn't parsed successfully.

Comment: i just cant do it, $info['date'] is a DATE field, and i tried this 
$timestamp = strtotime($info['date']);
$joined_date = date("j M. Y", $timestamp);
but again wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could format the date in the MySQL database server.

```
SELECT  *, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%e %b. %Y' ) AS formatted_date
FROM    `set` 
WHERE   ID = '$id'
```

Then you would just need to modify your client php code to just use the string returned by the database call in `$info['formatted_date']`.  Use 'd' in place of 'e' in the format string if you do not want a leading zero on the day of month.